# Ubuntu doesn't boot after fsck on /

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, fsck

I had this problem with Ubuntu when it boots: https://askubuntu.com/questions/392720/the-disk-drive-for-tmp-is-not-ready-yet-s-to-skip-mount-or-m-for-manual-recove

The problem appeared from nothing, that was weird. It was bothering me a lot, so I tried:

```
mount -o remount, rw /
```

Didn’t worked, so I did:

```
fsck /
```

After boot, I only see:

```
error: unknown filesystem.
grub rescue>
```

Doing ls I see:

```
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1)
```

Did ls ?/ in each one of those (? is the drive, e.g. (hd0,msdos1)) but I get:

```
error: unknown filesystem
```

Don’t know what to do from here.

I tried to boot from a LiveCD a try to reinstall Grub2, that didn’t worked, it seems that’s because I can’t mount /dev/sda1 which is my linux partition.

I also tried https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair from the LiveCD, but that doesn’t show the advanced options that help to repair the partition, I only see the “Create Boot Info summary” button. The summary is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/7880313/

I’m stuck, can’t boot or mount my disk (just need to mount it to do a backup and then maybe I can reinstall ubuntu, or another OS that gives less trouble).

Suggestions are very welcome.

Comment: Wait...how did you manage to do `fsck /`? `fsck` AFAIK cannot check a mounted partition, and the usage is like this: `fsck /dev/sdX`, not `fsck /mountpoint`.

Comment: I executed fsck / from the console that appears when clicking "M" after "The Disk Drive for /tmp is not ready yet. S to skip mount or M for manual recovery" appears (as I said, this was the original problem). NOT from a console inside an Ubuntu session.

That worked. Ubuntu tells you that might cause damage but just asks for confirmation and I said "yes", then fsck output a lot of errors (inodes pointing to the wrong sectors or something like that). Then after boot, got grub rescue>.

Comment: Running `fsck` on a mounted partition can cause data corruption -- probably your problem. The linked post that suggests running `fsck` does *not* say to run it on the mounted partition; if I understand it correctly, it wants you to run it on the `/dev/sdX` that *contains* the root partition.

Comment: So you did a *literal* `fsck /`? I still don't understand how it let you do that. `fsck` refuses to run if the filesystem is mounted.

Comment: I'm 90% sure it was fsck /, but I don't have the history since I executed it from the **Manual Recovery console**. Either way, yes I'm sure fsck broke something, maybe it messed up my boot sector and I can't either boot nor mount my linux partition. Now, I don't know how to proceed from the grub rescue, because **I can't reinstall grub2 and Boot-Repair doesn't seems to help**, it just can generate the boot info file pasted in my question.

Comment: Well, it seems that maybe it is time for you to reinstall Ubuntu and restore from backups.

Comment: Is that the only possible solution? There isn't any way to restore the MBR?

Comment: Your MBR is fine. If it wasn't, you wouldn't be getting into GRUB rescue prompt. The problem is, your root filesystem is corrupted, and GRUB can't find the 'second-stage bootloader' on it. That is also why GRUB says `unknown filesystem` when you try to do an `ls` on it. Oh, and you can't mount it from a LiveCD, can you? If you can't, your problem is a corrupted root filesystem, and your data is likely not recoverable (unless you are willing to spend lots of money on professional data recovery).